# .net Maui Shell navigation not working 2 levels down

Tags: c#, xamarin, maui

When navigating to the MainPage, I use this function `await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(MainPage)}");` it looks like it clears the LoginPage from the stack as the back button also doesn't appear.

When I navigate to PageOne with this code: `await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(PageOne));` I can navigate back. The problem comes when navigating to PageTwo. From PageTwo I can't navigate back. What am I don't wrong

Here is my MauiProgram.cs file:

```
...

services.AddSingleton<LoginPage>();
services.AddSingleton<LoginViewModel>();

services.AddSingleton<MainPage>();
services.AddSingleton<MainViewModel>();

services.AddSingleton<PageOnePage>();
services.AddSingleton<PageOneViewModel>();

services.AddSingleton<PageTwoPage>();
services.AddSingleton<PageTwoViewModel>();

...
```

Here I register my Routes in AppShell.xaml.cs:

```
Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(LoginPage), typeof(LoginPage));
Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(MainPage), typeof(MainPage));
Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(PageOnePage), typeof(PageOnePage));
Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(PageTwoPage), typeof(PageTwoPage));
```

I also have this I'm my AppShell.xaml:

```
<ShellContent
    Shell.NavBarIsVisible="true"
    Title="Login"
    ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoginPage}"
    Route="LoginPage" />

<ShellContent
    Shell.NavBarIsVisible="true"
    Title="Home"
    ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
    Route="MainPage" />

    
<ShellContent
    Shell.NavBarIsVisible="true"
    Title="PageOne"
    ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:PageOnePage}"
    Route="PageOnePage" />

<ShellContent
    Shell.NavBarIsVisible="true"
    Title="PageTwo"
    ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:PageTwoPage}"
    Route="PageTwoPage" />
```

Comment: Where do you register the route for PageOne / PageTwo?

Comment: You shoud read the [MAUI Shell-Navigation docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation)

Comment: @SirRufo I updated the Question. I tried to simplify my problem but forgot to to the same with the code in the files.

Comment: Well, have a look at the docs and see where and how they register the detail pages

Comment: @SirRufo I have looked at it and implemented some code that functions the same as their details page. But for some reason, I still cant navigate back to the previous page.
I use this code: ``` Task Back() => Shell.Current.GoToAsync($".."); ``` on a page that is one level down then It works. but when I'm 2 pages down it doesn't.

Comment: I have no problem with the navigation - look at the [sample project](https://github.com/SirRufo/so-MauiNavigation)

Comment: @SirRufo I do not think that singletons are his problem. The navigation cannot make sense of the way he defines his routes. I am 99.99% sure.

Comment: @H.A.H. Check out my working example, change the page service registration to singleton, run the app -> you get exactly what OP describes

Comment: @SirRufo You get exception about ambiguous routes?

Comment: @H.A.H. I posted a **working** example - what is unclear about **working** to you?

Comment: @SirRufo I did not ask you about your "working" example. I  am saying that the OP problem is with routes, not singletons.

Comment: @H.A.H. The OPs problem is that he cannot navigate back ... and that is caused by the singleton registration - OP thinks also, as he flagged my answer as accepted

Comment: @DuarteSomsen post what happens when you try to navigate back, so you end the discussion.

Comment: @H.A.H my routes weren't a problem at all. It was because of the Singletons. 

However, I did notice that if I added the MainPage as a Shellcontent and register a route for it, the application couldn't navigate to the MainPage. Which is logical if you think about it.

Comment: @DuarteSomsen You are telling me, that right now you have Route="PageOnePage" this, and Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(PageOnePage), typeof(PageOnePage)); at the same time? You registered them all at both places and it is working?

Comment: @H.A.H. I have the MainPage registered like this in AppShell.xaml
```<ShellContent
        Shell.NavBarIsVisible="true"
        Title="Home"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
        Route="MainPage" />``` 

and the rest like this in the Appshell.xaml.cs : ```Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(PageOnePage), typeof(PageOnePage));```

Comment: @DuarteSomsen So you removed the double registration of routes now? And you claim that your double registration of routes was not the problem?

Comment: @H.A.H. Yes... But now I see that I was wrong... Sorry about that. I think it's because At first, I didn't register them twice, but when I was busy trying ways to solve my back navigation problem, I did it like that(Which, of course didn't work. But I forgot to remove it) 

So with my initial problem, this wasn't the reason it didn't work. But when I posted the question I must have forgotten that I did that.

Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: After reading all this, I am confused. So, which was the problem? If it wasn’t Singletons, then please UNACCEPT that answer. You can still upvote it, if it was useful to you. But it is important for other programmers to know what the correct fix is!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must not register the pages as singleton if you want to use shell navigation.

Register them and their ViewModels as transient and now shell navigation will work as expected.

[Sample app @ github](https://github.com/SirRufo/so-MauiNavigation)

**Update** I extended the example for login page handling, you may find useful

Comment: This was indeed my main problem. However, I had some other issues as well. Thanks for the help and for checking it out!

Answer (score 1):

Code in question has TWO problems, both of which need to be fixed.

---

1. In MauiProgram.cs, add pages with `AddTransient`, not `AddSingleton`. This allows Shell navigation to create and destroy pages as needed:

```cs
services.AddTransient<LoginPage>();
```

NOTE: "ViewModel"s can be either AddTransient or AddSingleton. AddSingleton preserves model state between appearances of that page; AddTransient starts "fresh" each time.

Credit: [Sir Rufo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76263966/199364).

---

2. If going back, `Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..")`, gives "ambiguous routes" exception, AND the previous page is part of XAML hierarchy under AppShell, then REMOVE any explicit `RegisterRoute`:

```xml
<-- GIVEN this XAML -->
<AppShell ..
    ...
    <ShellContent
       ...
       ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
    />
```

```cs
// --- REMOVE this line: ---
//Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(MainPage), typeof(MainPage));
```

NOTE: Even if you don't have `Route="MainPage"` attribute in that declaration, being part of AppShell's hierarchy AUTOMATICALLY declares a route, and can result in "ambiguous route", if also declared in c#.

Comment: Sorry, but I can not reproduce that second point. I updated my [sample](https://github.com/SirRufo/so-MauiNavigation) doing "everything wrong" as you describe but I never get that "ambiguos route" exception. Instead it flips through the pages as expected. What am I not doing "wrong enough"? - It do not care who is wrong or right, I just can not reproduce it.

Comment: Maybe something has changed in Maui implementation, that avoids this. I’ll look through old SO Q&As.

Answer (score -1):

Let me guess the exception. It complains about ambiguous routes?

You have this:

```
Route="PageOnePage"
```

And this:

```
Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(PageOnePage), typeof(PageOnePage));
```

Make it registered at once place.
It will start working...

Comment: I can register a single page with thousands of routes ... no problem ... as long as they are registered as transient

Comment: Can you? And can you register thousands of pages with a single route?

Comment: You can register for each route any page you like - but only **one** per route. That should be obvious

Comment: @SirRufo Ok, so when its only one per route, what do you think happens when you do this what the OP does?

Comment: What do you think what happens? Did you use the debugger and had an eye on the `Routing` class `s_routes` field? You will be surprised what you see - or better - what you will not see in that dict. After seeing that, you will know why there is no exception in this case (question)

Comment: @SirRufo It throws System ArgumentException. Thats what happens. Ambiguous routes matched for...

Comment: Sorry, but I added in my working example the line `Routing.RegisterRoute( "MainPage", typeof( MainPage ) );` in `MauiProgram.cs` and ... surprise, surprise ... it works as before. So there must be something different what you are doing, but that is not what the OP is doing and therefor nort part of this question. You may want to post an example application on github so we can check out what you are doing wrong

Comment: @SirRufo Again, I do not ask you for "your example". I do not care for it. The OP , in the question is double defining the same routes twice. This will never work. It is part of his question.

Comment: And I proove with my example that it does work (and the OP never mentioned that there is an exception which bothers him) - So please post an example which throws that exception

Comment: @SirRufo You have double defined each route? In the XAML and in the code behind? Just like the OP ? And it works?!?

Comment: How many times should I repeat that? - I am out for now, until you proove your case with an example.

Comment: @SirRufo I will wait for you to provide a case with double definition instead. I am out until then.

Comment: Done. Its up to you

Comment: @SirRufo your appshell xaml cs is empty. There is no double definition in the code behind.

Comment: You can copy'paste the Register.Route lines from MauiProgram.cs to AppShell.xaml.cs, can you? And? - Again I wait for your proove.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I am not describing anything. It is right there in the OP question. I just pointed it out.